Help Need Loading Full Calendar 6.1.15 In LWC
I could really use some help here trying to get Full Calendar 6.1.15 to run in a LWC;
I have Full Calendar zip loaded as a resource in my sandbox:
Name: FullCalendar

MIME Type: application/x-zip-compressed

My code in my HTML file is:
<template>
    <div class="iV_CourseScheduleCalendar">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
             <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

My JS code is as follows:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

import fullCalendar from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/FullCalendar";

export default class IV_CourseScheduleCalendar extends LightningElement 
{
     async connectedCallback()
     {
     }

     async renderedCallback() 
     {

        console.log('Start: Load Calendar Script'),
        await loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/fullcalendar-6.1.15/dist/index.global.js"),
        console.log('End: Load Calendar Script')

        console.log('Start: Build Calendar');
        var calendarContainer  = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarContainer, 
        {

            headerToolbar: 
            {
                left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
            },
            initialDate: '2024-01-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            dayMaxEvents: true // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    
        calendar.render();
        console.log('End: Build Calendar')
    }
}

I kind of followed the Full Calendar month view example in the zip file from the site but I just keep getting errors in my console log when I try and view my LWC in salesforce.

I am really at a loss on why this will not load any help would be great.... Thanks

You cannot use document.getElementById('someId'); nor this.template.querySelector('#someId') in LWC since the framework changes the Ids when a component renders. Doc

Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it won’t match the transformed ID.

Therefore calendarContainer will be null, resulting in an exception when FullCalendar tries to use it.
You could leverage lwc:ref directive to get the reference to a specific DOM element.
Moreover since FullCalendar needs to manipulate the DOM, that element needs lwc:dom="manual" directive too.
Moreover you should load the script in the connectedCallback, and use a flag to run the code in the renderedCallback only once. Currently you try to load the script at each render cycle.
The HTML should be:
<template>
    <div class="iV_CourseScheduleCalendar">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
             <div lwc:dom="manual" lwc:ref="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Then in JS:
fullCalendarLoaded = false;
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Start: Load Calendar Script');
    loadScript(this, fullCalendar + "/fullcalendar-6.1.15/dist/index.global.js")
        .then(() => {
            this.fullCalendarLoaded = true;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Failed to load Calendar:', error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log('End: Load Calendar Script:', this.fullCalendarLoaded);
        });
}

renderedOnce = false;
async renderedCallback() {
    if (!this.renderedOnce && this.fullCalendarLoaded) {
        this.renderedOnce = true;
        console.log('Start: Build Calendar');
        const calendarContainer  = this.refs.calendar;
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarContainer, 
        {
            headerToolbar: 
            {
                left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
            },
            initialDate: '2024-01-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            dayMaxEvents: true // allow "more" link when too many events
        });

        calendar.render();
        console.log('End: Build Calendar')
    }
}

By the way, you should prefer const and let over var.

Thanks for your suggestions I will make the changes, but it really does not address the script loading issue. The error looks to be happening during "await loadScript"

@AndrewDay I updated the answer. The script should be loaded in the connectedCallback, moreover in almost every case you need a flag to avoid running the code in the renderedCallback multiple times. In this case you're trying to load the script each time the component rerender.

I really appreciate all your help with this. The changes did not fix the issue I am having. The calendar still does not load and I still get the errors shown in the image in the post above. I also just wanted to add that I am getting the errors above when the LWC is hosted in a screen flow but I also added to a DE site and get the same "011Y" error but not the "malformed error".  Maybe the new "full calendar" will not work in salesforce anymore
